# Google app engine (python) doesn't show image

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have `<p><img src="/images/logo.png"></p>` in my html file.

I have added an image handler to my app.yaml and checked that the order of handlers are fine.

The image is in the images folder under the root directory, but still can't see the image. Could someone help please?

This is my app.yaml

```
runtime: python37

handlers:

- url: /static

  static_dir: static

- url: /images

  static_dir: images

  mime_type: image/png

- url: /.*

  script: auto
```

Comment: what does "can't see the image" mean exactly? 404? Not displayed in the browser? Something else?

Comment: a broken image icon shows up and if you right click on the icon and copy the image address and paste on the search bar you would get 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason when you deploy the app, you will be able to see the images also even if the app is not deployed if you pass a link address to the src attribute instead of a relative path it would still work.

Answer (score 0):

Your app.yaml is all good.

You can test further to see if the image is uploaded.

1. Once deployed, inspect your page with a link like project-id.appspot.com

   - If it returns a `404` response, the image path can be wrong or the 
     `logo.png` file is missing
   - Check the *Sources* tab if the `image` folder is present together with the file.
2. Verify if the image folder is in proper place as well as the `logo.png` does exist.
3. Check the html file if the `img src` is correct. Sometimes, it's just typo error on their link or file name

You can also add try to edit then deploy this [sample code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard_python37/building-an-app/building-an-app-1) and simply add an images folder. It worked for me.